# Twitter API Notifications Timeline

Tags: twitter

Using the Twitter REST API, is it possible to get a list of notification timeline items?

I'm after the notification timeline:
[image: notification timeline]

I've found a [mentions timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/mentions_timeline) but no notification timeline. The mentions timeline is simpler than the notification timeline, only showing direct replies:
[image: mentions timeline]

If there isn't a simple API call for this, what's the best way to get the information I need? (e.g. users which have favourited a tweet, users which have retweeted a tweet, users which have followed you)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is apparently "No".

Answer (score 1):

Twitter has an API called [Site Streams](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/sitestreams), but it is a closed beta that is not accepting applications. Looks like all us indie devs have to use polling for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they've added it, it's available at:
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json

Comment: Please avoid answering questions with only a link. Also, the link does not work: "Could not authenticate you."

Comment: Sorry that is the way to pull the mentions.The full docs are available at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-mentions_timeline.